# pandas - two-dimensional histogram and averages

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have a dataframe that is made of two columns, for example:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 8492 | 119748 |
| 10581 | 106092 |
| 10409 | 114885 |
| 9812 | 162303 |
| 9676 | 105570 |
| 10162 | 66298 |
| 9042 | 50838 |
| 8646 | 114050 |
| 9531 | 117002 |
| 9151 | 90112 |

I would like to generate a histogram of the items in column x with bin size 500 (for example) but have another column that gives me the average of those values in column y for that bin.

So the result table would look something like:

|  | Count x | Avg y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8000 | 0 | 0 |
| 8500 | 1 | 119748 |
| 9000 | 1 | 114050 |
| 9500 | 2 | 70475 |
| 10000 | 3 | 128292 |
| 10500 | 2 | 90592 |
| 11000 | 1 | 106092 |

In this case I am showing the average, but I would like to have an option of collecting the min y, max y, median y.

I can write a function in Python that will do this, but wondering if there is any native way to do this with Pandas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want an aggregation with grouping over bins (or in pandas "cuts").

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x" : [8492, 10581, 10409, 9812, 9676, 10162, 9042, 8646, 9531, 9151],
    "y" : [119748, 106092, 114885, 162303, 105570, 66298, 50838, 114050, 117002, 90112]
    })
```

The binning limits could be more thought through, but it does the job.

```
bins_size = 500
bins = np.arange(
    (df.x.min()// bins_size) * bins_size, 
    (((df.x.max()// bins_size) + 1) * bins_size) + 1, 
    bins_size)
```

You can add whatever you want to the `agg()` in the same manner such as `"min"`, `"max"` or even lambda functions (without quotes of course). Regarding `"count"` it would not matter whether you pick x or y as long as neither has a NULL value within the group.

```
print(df
    .assign(bined = lambda var : pd.cut(var.x, bins))
    .groupby(["bined"])
    .agg(
        mean_y = ("y", "mean"),
        median_y = ("y", "median"),
        count = ("x", "count"))
    .reset_index()
    )
```

This will result in the table below:

```
            bined         mean_y  median_y  count
0    (8000, 8500]  119748.000000  119748.0      1
1    (8500, 9000]  114050.000000  114050.0      1
2    (9000, 9500]   70475.000000   70475.0      2
3   (9500, 10000]  128291.666667  117002.0      3
4  (10000, 10500]   90591.500000   90591.5      2
5  (10500, 11000]  106092.000000  106092.0      1
```